# Geodesicity of horizontal lifts for non-degenerate anisotropic metrics

Tags: differential-geometry

For $ \sigma : M \to N $ a submersion of a finite dimensional differentiable manifold $ M $ onto a lower dimensional base manifold, that is to say for $ TM $ and $ TN $ their respective tangent bundles and $ \pi = \pi_M : TM \to M $, $ \pi_N : TN \to N $ the associated projections onto base points the differential $ \mathrm{d} \sigma : TM \to TN $ be surjective on each tangent plane, and considering a non-degenerate anisotropic metric tensor $ g : (v,x,y) \mapsto g_v(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} $ for $ v \in TM $ and $ x,y \in T_{\pi(v)} M $ inducing $ h : (v,x,y) \mapsto h_v(x,y) $ for $ v \in TN $ and $ x,y \in T_{\pi_N(v)} N $ such that: $$ \forall v \in TM : g_v(v,\cdot)\vert_{\ker\mathrm{d}\sigma \cap T_{\pi(v)} M} \equiv 0 , \,\, g_v(v,v) = h_{\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot v}(\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot v,\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot v) $$
let us refer to the condition on $ v $ as $ g $-horizontality, and define $ g_v $-horizontality of $ w \in T_{\pi(v)} $ as the condition: $$ g_v(w,\cdot)\vert_{\ker\mathrm{d}\sigma \cap T_{\pi(v)} M} \equiv 0 $$
inspired by the differentiation of the condition $ g_\gamma(\gamma,\cdot) = 0 $ for a $ g $-horizontal curve $ \gamma : \mathbb{R} \to T_{\pi(v)} M $ through $ v $ with velocity $ w $, provided the vertical derivative $ \partial^
\text{v.} g : (v,x,y,z) \mapsto \frac{\partial g_{v+tz}(x,y)}{\partial t} \vert_{t=0} $ of $ g $ verifies $ (\partial^\text{v.} g)_v(v,y,z) = 0 $.

Let us assume that we are able to prove: $$ g_v(x,y) = h_{\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot v}(\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot x,\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot y) $$
for any $ g $-horizontal $ v \in TM $ and $ g_v $-horizontal $ x,y \in T_{\pi(v)} M $. Let us furthermore assume that we are also able to identify the vertical derivatives of $ g $ and $ h $ in a similar fashion. We may even have for some vertical anisotropic tensor $ \Lambda $: $$ (\partial^\text{v.} g)_v(x,y,\cdot)\vert_{\ker\mathrm{d}\sigma \cap T_{\pi(v)} M} = g_v(\Lambda_v(x,y),\cdot)\vert_{\ker\mathrm{d}\sigma \cap T_{\pi(v)} M} $$
The anisotropic analogue of the Levi-Civita connection would be the Chern connection, defined as the unique torsion-free anisotropic linear connection $ \nabla : (v,x,Y) \mapsto \nabla^v_x Y \in T_{\pi(v)} M $ for $ Y \in \mathfrak{X}(M) $ with: $$ zg_V(X,Y) = g_v(\nabla^v_zX,y)+g_v(x,\nabla^v_zY)+(\partial^\text{v.} g)_v(x,y,\nabla^v_zV) $$ for any $ v \in TM $, $ x,y,z \in T_{\pi(v)} M $ and arbitrary extensions $ V,X,Y,Z \in \mathfrak{X}(M) $. Such a connection is well defined, as it leads to a familiar Koszul formula, differing from the Riemannian case by only some vertical derivative terms. Both $ (M,g) $ and $ (N,h) $ have their associated Chern connection, with respect to which we may consider geodesics $ \gamma $ verifying $ \nabla^{\dot\gamma}_{\dot\gamma} \dot\gamma = 0 $.

From there, it should be straightforward to prove that an anywhere horizontal geodesic is horizontal everywhere. My intuition was that if the $ g $-horizontal lift of geodesics of $ (N,h) $ makes geodesics of $ (M,g) $, then, by uniqueness of geodesics of $ (M,g) $ through $ \gamma(t) $ with velocity $ \dot\gamma(t) $, if a geodesic $ \gamma $ is $ g $-horizontal at $ t \in \mathbb{R} $, it must match the $ g $-horizontal lift of the geodesic of $ (N,h) $ through $ \sigma(\gamma(t)) $ with velocity $ \mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot\dot\gamma(t) $ and consequently be $ g $-horizontal everywhere.

This single sentence proof requires that the $ g $-horizontal lift of a geodesic of $ (N,h) $ consistently produce geodesics of $ (M,g) $, which I find difficult to make manifest since a priori: $$ \mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot \nabla^V_X Y - \nabla^{\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot V}_{\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot X} (\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot Y) $$
is generally not even constant along submersion fibres for $ \mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot V $, $ \mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot X $ and $ \mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot Y $ constant on submersion fibres. I am starting to doubt the geodesicity of $ g $-horizontal lifts to begin with. Is there an obvious counterexample, or some reference on the matter?

Edit: I believe I have managed to prove that $ \mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot \nabla^V_X Y - \nabla^{\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot V}_{\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot X} (\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot Y) $ is indeed constant on submersion fibres for basic vector fields, by taking the difference of the Koszul formulae to obtain an expression of: $$ g_V(\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot \nabla^V_X Y - \nabla^{\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot V}_{\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot X} (\mathrm{d}\sigma\cdot Y),Z) $$
in terms of $ \partial^\text{v.} g $, symmetric in $ X,Y $, tensorial in $ X,Y,Z $ and depending only on $ V $ at one point, while having a dependence on $ \mathrm{d} \sigma \cdot V $. It is therefore still plausible that the $ g $-horizontal lift of geodesics produce geodesics.